# python: recurcive list processing changes original list

Tags: python, list, recursion

What I'm trying to do is recursively process a list. I'm new to python so when all the code was written and sent to be executed I faced a strange problem: the list returns changed after calling the recursive function. To test this I wrote that:

```
def recur(n):
    n.append(len(n))
    print '>',n
    if n[-1]<5: recur(n)
    print '<',n
```

And called the function:

```
recur([])
```

Here was the result:

```
> [0]
> [0, 1]
> [0, 1, 2]
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What I expected to see was

```
> [0]
> [0, 1]
> [0, 1, 2]
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
< [0, 1, 2, 3]
< [0, 1, 2]
< [0, 1]
< [0]
```

, as it is for simple integer variables:

```
def recur(n):
    n=n+1
    print '>',n
    if n<5: recur(n)
    print '<',n

recur(0)
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
< 5
< 4
< 3
< 2
< 1
```

How can I fix the situation and what have I understood wrong?

Comment: Your question "python: recurcive list processing" is not question.

Comment: @PhilFrost, but "How can I fix the situation and what have I understood wrong?" is a question.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I can't tell if you are being sarcastic or not. I'm not saying this is a bad question; I'm saying that the big heading at the top is not phrased as a question. This is important, because when someone is confused about how their list is being mutated, they are not going to search for "recursive list processing". They might search for something like "Why does my list change each time I call a function?"

Comment: @PhilFrost, Your criticism was unclear, and seemed unjust. I don't think a heading must be phrased as a question, but I agree that it should be more closely related to the problem. Hope my edit is an improvement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the recursive invocations of your function operate on the same list. You need to make a copy:

```
def recur(n):
    n.append(len(n))
    print '>',n
    if n[-1]<5: recur(n[:])  # <<<< Note the [:]
    print '<',n
```

There are some good explanations in the answers to [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers indicated, you are mutating the list in place. You could make copies of the list and/or use an immutable data structure, like a tuple:

```
def recur(n=()):
    if len(n) > 4:
         return n
    return recur(n + (len(n),))
```